# how to extract excel data in python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, xlrd

I want to statistic data from excel in python, but now I cannot extract the data

my code

```
import pandas as pd

import xlrd

file = 'Book1.xlsx'

x1 = pd.ExcelFile(file)

Print(x1.sheet_names)


results:
C:\Users\ldanl\PycharmProjects\1011\venv\Scripts\python.exe 
C:/Users/ldanl/PycharmProjects/1011/draft.py
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:/Users/ldanl/PycharmProjects/1011/draft.py", line 82, in <module> x1 = pd.ExcelFile(file)  

File"C:\Users\ldanl\PycharmProjects\1011\venv\lib\sitepackages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 394, in __init__    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(self._io)

File "C:\Users\ldanl\PycharmProjects\1011\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 141, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,

File "C:\Users\ldanl\PycharmProjects\1011\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 808, in open_workbook_2007_xml
    x12book.process_stream(zflo, 'Workbook')

 File "C:\Users\ldanl\PycharmProjects\1011\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 265, in process_stream
    meth(self, elem)

 File "C:\Users\ldanl\PycharmProjects\1011\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py", line 392, in do_sheet
    sheet = Sheet(bk, position=None, name=name, number=sheetx)

  File "C:\Users\ldanl\PycharmProjects\1011\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd\sheet.py", line 326, in __init__
    self.extract_formulas = book.extract_formulas
```

> AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'extract_formulas'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Have you tried `pd.read_excel()`

Comment: Yes, the same erro

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, are you sure you posted your code correctly? Or are you sure the content of `Book1.xlsx` is correct?

Comment: @toti08 I copied my code. And I don’t know what kind of data should be in the excel. In my Book1, they are the relationship between different concentrations and zeta potential. I think they are not complexible

Comment: The results you're showing are the names of the `sheets` in your excel files?

Comment: @LoveDanny can you print the version number of your `xlrd` library?

Comment: The version is 1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

For Pandas --> Try `pd.read_excel()`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel

For Xlrd --> Try `xlrd.open_workbook()`

https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.open_workbook